# How to avoid double scrollbars when using class CSplitterWndEx

Tags: mfc, splitter, csplitterwnd

I created an application with the MFC wizard and added the splitter functionality.

The wizard will add a variable `CSplitterWndEx m_wndSplitter` to class `CChildFrame`.

After that, a split view will be created with a horizontal scrollbar and a vertical scrollbar.

But the rich edit view also has its own scroll bar.

How can I keep only one scrollbar and keep the split functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you say "After that, a split view will be created with a horizontal scrollbar and a vertical scrollbar"? You will only get scrollbars if the CView-derived class inside the splitter pane has a scrollbar.

Comment: I have no enough reputation to insert a picture, please refer to the following link which can show my case:
http://a.pictureupload.us/2098357751513f28be4a4c8.png
Thank you.

Comment: What are you putting in the splitter panes? Are you using a CScrollView, CEditView, CView, what?

Comment: Yes, I use a CRichEditView. How can I avoid the double scrollbars?

Comment: I haven't checked but one way is to override PreCreateWindow() and make sure you remove WS_VSCROLL from the window style. Maybe you also need to look at the size of your view with respect to the size of the splitter pane.

Comment: Finally I didn't find a solution for this.
I used SetScrollStyle(0) to hide the scrolllbar for the splitter window.
But I have a new issue now. How can I split the window now?
I cannot split the window by double clicking the up-right corner of the scrollbar, because the scrollbar is hidden now.
I'd like use a command from menu to split the window. Which API should I use to split the window.
By the way, I used a dynamic view.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bar is created with respected to the style given on creation of splitter window.  Please refer the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/csplitterwnd-class?view=msvc-170#create

if the style is modified as below, the scrollbars will not be created

DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SPLS_DYNAMIC_SPLIT.

To show the Splitter for dynamic split, we need the scrollbars which creates space to display the splitter.